# How can I get the right Pandas series index when plot with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a Pandas series with Matplotlib, but I get the error message:

> index type not supported.

Here's my code:

```
inputX = values_dataset[:,:-horizon]
inputX = inputX.reshape(inputX.shape[0], time_steps, dim)
yhat = model.predict(inputX)
yhat = scalery.inverse_transform(yhat)
series_actual = series.loc[Syhat.index[0]:Syhat.index[-1]]

Syhat_native = {}
if get_transform_status(target_var) == 1:
    for i in range(horizon):
        Syhat_horizoni = pd.Series(yhat[:,i], index= train_val_test_time).iloc[i:]
        
        series_shift = series_actual.shift(i).dropna()
        Syhat_native[i] = inv_diff(series_shift, Syhat_horizoni, 12)
else:
    for i in range(horizon):
        # The code goes here
        Syhat_horizoni = pd.Series(yhat[:,i], index= train_val_test_time)
        Syhat_native[i] = Syhat_horizoni.shift(i)
```

Here's the code when I want have a plot:

```
#now we plot the 
if horizon>1:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, horizon, figsize=[horizon*10,5])
    for i in range(horizon):
        Syactual_horizoni= series_actual.shift(i)
        Syactual_horizoni.plot(ax=ax[i], color='b',label = 'actual')
        
        # This line below where the error occured
        Syhat_native[i].plot(ax=ax[i], color='r', label = 'pred')

        ax[i].set_title('horizon-'+str(i))
        ax[i].legend()
        ax[i].axvline(train_time[-1])
        
#     fig.savefig("./visualization/LSTM-bidirectional-Covid-h14/LSTM-Bidirectional-Covid-Transformed-1.png")
    fig.suptitle('TRAIN+TEST SET inversed',fontsize=20 )
```

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

i already got the answer, the `Syhat_native` series index is not in datetime format. so i did this

```
inputX = values_dataset[:,:-horizon]
inputX = inputX.reshape(inputX.shape[0], time_steps, dim)
yhat = model.predict(inputX)
yhat = scalery.inverse_transform(yhat)
series_actual = series.loc[Syhat.index[0]:Syhat.index[-1]]

Syhat_native = {}
if get_transform_status(target_var) == 1:
    for i in range(horizon):
        Syhat_horizoni = pd.Series(yhat[:,i], index= train_val_test_time).iloc[i:]
        
        series_shift = series_actual.shift(i).dropna()
        Syhat_native[i] = inv_diff(series_shift, Syhat_horizoni, 12)
else:
    for i in range(horizon):
        # The code goes here
        Syhat_horizoni = pd.Series(yhat[:,i], index= train_val_test_time)
   
        Syhat_native[i] = Syhat_horizoni.shift(i)
        Syhat_native[i].index = pd.to_datetime(Syhat_native[i].index)
```